# replace the value from last index of array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

i have an array that looks like this

```
let = ["1", "0", "0", "0", ".", "0", "0"]
```

i want to change the value of last index and then constantly move to the indexes of 0's

for example i want to input 5,3,2. the output should become

```
updatedArray = ["1", "0", "0", "5", ".", "3", "2"]
```

is this possible?

i tried this to check for the indexes of 0

```
const stringValueArray = stringValue.split('');

const emptyStringIndices: number[] = [];
          stringValueArray.forEach((element, index) => {
            if (element === '0') {
              emptyStringIndices.push(index);
            }
          });
const highestIndex = Math.max(...emptyStringIndices);

       stringValueArray[highestIndex] = value;

const newValue = stringValueArray.join('');
 return newValue;
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, what you are looking for is the code that adds a number to 1000.00 and splits it into an array. In that case, why don't you simply divide the number you want to add to 1000.00 by 100 (e.g., 532/100 = 5.32), and then add this 5.32 to 1000.00, resulting in 1005.32. Finally, you can split it into an array, which will give you ["1", "0", "0", "5", ".", "3", "2"].

Comment: btw, what is the purpose of the task? why do you have strings for numbers?

Comment: @NinaScholz i'm making a school project. i have a keypad that values 0-9 and a 
quick cash button that gives me an instant value of 500.00 and 1000.00. im finding a way to change the 0's in them whenever i press my keypad. like a calculator but i have an initial value of which quick cash button i choose

Comment: i would calculate with integers and add the point at the last step only for display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep track of the original digits and the new digits entered. This is necessary, because you may need to enter 402 to get 1004.02, and you would not want the code to get confused and give 1000.42 as the result because it did not realise that the zero you entered needs to stay.

It is assumed that the input always contains the decimal place followed by two decimal numbers.

Then, get the result by combining the original digits with the entered digits, taking care to re-insert the decimal point before returning the result.

If too many digits are entered, ignore any excess digits.

```js
class Keypad {
  constructor(s) {
    this.origDigits = [...s].filter(c =>c !=='.');
    this.maxKeyPresses = this.origDigits.filter(c => c==='0').length;
    this.keyPresses = [];
  }
  keyPressed(n) {
    if(this.keyPresses.length < this.maxKeyPresses) this.keyPresses.push(n);
  }
  get val() {
    let digits = [
      ...this.origDigits.slice(0, this.origDigits.length - this.keyPresses.length),
      ...this.keyPresses
    ];
    digits.splice(-2, 0, '.');
    return digits.join('');
  }
}

let k = new Keypad('1000.00');
console.log(k.val);
k.keyPressed(5);
console.log(k.val);
k.keyPressed(3);
console.log(k.val);
k.keyPressed(2);
console.log(k.val);
```

Comment: This definitely works! thanks for your idea. I just converted it to work on my react native project

Answer (score 0):

**New answer**,

On second thought, if you `reverse` the `data` array, you can `map()`  over it, return `input.pop()` if there is some (`|| c`) as fallback, and then reverse it again.

```js
let data = ["1", "0", "0", "0", ".", "0", "0"],
    input = [ "5", "3", "2" ];

data.reverse();

data = data.map((c, i) => (c === "0") ? (input.pop() || c) : c).reverse();

console.log(data)
```

---

**Original answer**:

You can create a loop, in which you hold a flag for the last changed index.

Then check if that index is equal to `"0"`, if so, replace it with the last item in the changed array, using `pop()` so we can use `input.length` as the `while` condition

```js
let data = ["1", "0", "0", "0", ".", "0", "0"],
    input = [ "5", "3", "2" ];


let lastIndex = data.length - 1;
while (input.length && lastIndex > 0) {
    if (data[lastIndex] == 0) {
        data[lastIndex] = input.pop();
    }
    lastIndex--;
}

console.log(data)
```

Comment: Initial lastIndex value is incorrect, or its use in `if (data[lastIndex] == 0)`.

Comment: ^^ `let lastIndex = data.length -1;` , saves a loop.. :)

Comment: thank you for your answer. its working but in my case i can only input the 5,3,2 one by one

Comment: The fix isn't that simple. It ignores the first element of data, so if `data[0]` is "0" and `input` is long enough, the code won't replace data[0].